# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: select#state_id option[value=]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

The syntax looks right to me. I've never done a lot of joins before, but I need those columns in a table which is cross referenced by various ids.

I have 3 select option which looks like this. I have the following code which is supposed to select the value from a select drop down :

```
select.append('<option  value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');
```

[image: state]

Comment: If you look at the error you can see that city_id returns nothing aka `""` try use `$("select#city_id option[value='"+city_id+"']")`

Comment: Thank you for answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Can you answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191037/how-to-select-option-when-after-select-an-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that if `data[i].id` is null then it will not work. so you need to wrap `+data[i].id+` in `''`

like `select.append('<option  value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');`

Comment: -  Can you answer this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191037/how-to-select-option-when-after-select-an-option